# Shouldn't the tour of this bilingual site be bilingual?

Tags: feature-request

The very first sentence of the [german.stackexchange-tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour) after the welcome-heading is this:
<sup>(emphasis added by me)</sup>

> German Language and Usage is a ***bilingual*** question and answer site ***for speakers of German*** [...]

But the whole tour is in English. Isn't it a bit strange, that the tour of a **bilingual** site is completely monolingual, and that on a tour for a site **for speakers of German** you can't find any German word? Even the example-questions and -answers are in English!

I see the need of a tour in English. But there are thousands of people who want to discuss about German language, who are weak in English, because English is a foreign language to them, or who even don't speak English at all. Those people need a tour in an other language then English, and since 100% of all visitors of german.stackexchange are interested in German Language, I think this other language should be German.

Therefore I suggest, that there should be two tours. One in English and the other completely in German, with prominently links on each tour to the other one.

Comment: related http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/839/let-s-make-a-german-welcome-page-faq-for-visitors-who-speak-little-or-no-english and http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/33/interface-localization-to-german

Answer (score 5):

The only solution I see to the incompleteness-feeling regarding the missing German translations of the many pages this site has, is to create the German interface. The proposal of this answer is to be able to access that German interface with the following conditions.

1. Asking in English is always allowed.
2. Answering to English questions in English is what is expected.
3. The site does not split, neither do the user's accounts (see *background* below)

---

### Background

I was surprised to notice that the [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) has a sister-site
with a (purely) Russian interface, namely

https://rus.stackexchange.com/

Maybe that's what the solution to your series of questions might be: to create a

*deutsch.stackexchange.com*

(that page does exist, but it redirects to the usual GL.SE) which displays a German interface but which, opposite to that what happened to the Russian site, does transfer your reputation and considers you as owning one account with one reputation, independent on the language you choose to read the interface. **It would be a pity that the reputation might not be transferred, as it happens in the Russian language sites. That would, IMHO, make this site weaker**, instead of prompting its growth.

Answer (score 2):

The first paragraph

> German Language and Usage is a bilingual question and answer site for speakers of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translation. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the German language.

of the tour is editable. So we are able to add a German paragraph there if there is a community consent on the wording.

Also we are free to choose a different example question for the tour if we find another question to fit better. We have to keep in mind that from the limited space on the tour it should preferably be a short to very short example.

So it is all up to us to make suggestions for the community to vote upon.

Comment: The english tour is good, I wouldn't change it. I suggest to create a second tour, that is a 1:1-copy of it, with the only difference, that the copy is in German language. With 1:1-translations of all explanations and all examples. The only thing that I really would change on the existing English tour is, that I would add there be a prominent link to the German tour. (And vice versa)

Comment: It would need a stack exchange developer to implement this feature - so unfortunately it is not a thing we can easily get on a beta site.

Answer (score 2):

[I set up a German help page here on Meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/977/2594), whose first item should be a German tour. This should be the best we can do with the available resources.